# How to change WooCommerce shipping method with JavaScript trigger, or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I added some JavaScript code in my theme woocommerce checkout page where I am getting two fields value using javascrpit

> 1 billing_state
>
> 2- Custom Field (billing_delivery_date)

After matching these values I want to update the WooCommerce shipping method as mentioned in alert call. I have configure two shipping methods

> 1 Flat Rate
>
> 2 Free Shipping

for your reference code is mentioned below:

```
  function getId(element) { 
        document.getElementById('billing_delivery_date').value = "";
        var ro = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var pro = ro - 1;
        var co = element.parentNode.cellIndex;
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];  
        var xr = table.rows[pro].cells[co].innerHTML; 
        var yr = xr.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ' ')
        var zr = yr.split(';');
        var zrr = zr[1].split('  ');
        var txt1 = zrr[0] + zr[2] ;     
        document.getElementById('billing_delivery_date').value += window.txt1;
        var format = txt1.includes('Tue');
        if(( format == true ) && (window.state == 'DXB') ){     
            jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout", { update_shipping_method: true }); 
            alert("Free Shipping")
        }else{
            alert("Flat Rate");
        }               
    }
```

Please help if any clue.

Comment: I don't understand of what depends the shipping method ?

Comment: Actually i am using custom javascript code the give an option to customers to select delivery dates. and send orders. 
I receive value billing_delivery_date value in this formate e.g. 18/11 Mon | 19/11/Tue. 
But i want to make free shipping on weekday "Tue" for specific billing_state like you see in code DXB.
The above code working fine and it trigger the checkout page but the issue shipping method not change from Flat rate to free shipping.